# how to change what function returns without changing header file

Tags: c, function, struct

For an assignment we must use a predetermined header file - I can not make any changes to it.

However most of the functions return a node (a struct node), but I would like them to return a pointer to the node.

Is there any way to change the function call in my `functions.c` file?

If not once the node is returned how can I have a pointer point to it??

For example:

```
bst_node_t BSTSearchNode( bst_root_t root, bst_key_t key, cmp_func_t cmp_func );
```

is the function prototype in the header file. However I would like to return a pointer to a node instead of the node itself.

Comment: Do you have to use that particular header-file and these particular functions? If so, you can't change it. Or you need to redefine the functions.

Comment: Are you sure the `bst_node_t` isn't a pointer already?

Comment: Why would you want to change these prototypes? Good compilers are able to optimize out copies that would be induced by returning a struct in many cases. Since this is an assignment, this should not be your concern. Concentrate on realizing the API as requested.

Comment: i thought it was a pointer because it's defined as typedef void* bst_node_t  however when i try to write node = NULL it says that's not valid\

Comment: If there is a `typedef void *bst_node_t;`, then `bst_node_t` **is** a pointer. But hiding pointers behind typedefs is evil. Can you show the header?

Comment: which part of the header?

Comment: @EstherKarp - if it's not long, the whole thing. If it is, at least any `typedefs` that are in there any the structures that you're using for the "nodes" of your BST

Comment: typedef void* bst_key_t;
typedef void* bst_val_t;
typedef void* bst_node_t;
typedef bst_node_t bst_root_t;

typedef enum {FAIL = -1, SUCCESS} result_t;
those are the typedefs and the structs are :typedef struct bst_node_t {
 bst_key_t key;
 struct valueList_t* list;
 struct bst_node_t* left;
 struct bst_node_t* right;
};

typedef struct valueList_s{
 bst_val_t value;
 struct valueList_s* next;
} valueList_t;
but im not sure that i defined them properly...

Answer (score 2):

No you can't, the function declarations and definitions have to match.

Out of curiosity will the assignement be checked with a programm, that would link with your implementation, and try and call the BSTSearchNode function ? In which case, you really want to define it the right way...

Edit : following your comment, your assignement is really to implement the function as defined, and not change its return type. So, just do that ;)

It might actually be simpler to keep passing the value around as asked (if you try to pass a pointer to the data, you'll have to be carefull about where the memory for the node is allocated, who owns it, etc...). The API from your header might not be adapted to this.

Of course, this also applies if `bst_node_t` is a typedef to a pointer to some entity, in which case you have nothing to change. Hard to tell without the header...

Comment: yeah an automated program checks it...so do you know how when it is returned i can change it to a pointer? is that possible?

Comment: so what i dont understand is that i am supposed to be working with a binary tree and the bst_node_t is part of the struct but not the struct itself so when it is returned how can i access the whole node?

Comment: We can't tell you that without the header (the bst_node_t is really specific to your case.) You should study the definition of the type, and for this kind of questions, your teacher / teacher assistants are better suited than SO :) Good luck to you.

Comment: And in your case, if your question is "how can I access the bst_root_t from a bst_node_t", is there a relation between a node and its parent ?

Comment: my question is more how to i turn the typedef void* bst_node_t into a struct?